# Web search for filename using Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I'm attempting to formulate an Automator script that takes a filename from Finder and searches for it on a specific website using Google.

It looks like I'm getting the filename right and can put it in a variable, but I can't figure out if there is a way to pass the variable to the search URL. There is no variable input field for URLs. Can perhaps some intermediate function be used?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script, it return an **URL** (no need for other actions or variables):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set tName to name of (info for (item 1 of input) without size)
    return "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & tName & "%20site%3Amywebpage.com"
end run
```